# excel vba remove duplicates and sum corresponding values

Tags: excel, vba

I found this code but i can't get it to work for my cell range. My example is below. "Corrected Order" is in col C, "Qty" is in col D. I want to remove the duplicates in col C, summing the corresponding values in col D and paste into range F1:G40. The code below works if I copy&paste col C to Col A, otherwise it removes duplicates but values are all "0"??

```
A   B   C   D
    Corrected Order (LCP)   Qty
    Orange  12
    Pear    9
    Pear    9
    Pear    6
    Orange  6
    Orange  3
    Orange  1
    Apple   34
    Apple   4
    Apple   4
    Apple   67



Option Explicit

Sub main()

With Worksheets("Fruit Stock") '<== change "Fruit Stock" as per your actual sheet name

    With .Range("C1:D40").Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row)
        .Copy
        With .Offset(, .Columns.Count + 1)
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues ' copy value and formats
            .Columns(2).Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(C1,RC1,C[-" & .Columns.Count + 1 & "])"
            .Value = .Value
            .RemoveDuplicates 1, xlYes
        End With
    End With

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to remove the duplicate fruit names but add the values of all fruits. So one line for Pears showing 24 total?

Comment: A pivot table will do this.

Comment: No I have different data below and across from this range. I have reserved 2 columns for this consolidated data. I know I could use the consolidated function to do this but I want a quick command button macro as I will be doing this function regularly

Comment: Sorry just to reply to the first reply, yes that is what i want Pears 24 in a shifted column

Comment: Why not just use an if statement to make the SUMIF equation, where reference is blank or not found, to display ""?

Comment: I can get this code to work perfectly if i work on range A1:B40, I just guess I have my offsets wrong. It seems to be looking in col A for a reference??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the correction to the "CX, RCX" where X is your column number (X=3 for Column C)
Also corrected a few absolute addresses which meant that it only worked for the one case. Esp the Resizing to 3 columns didn't make sense.

```
Sub main()

With ActiveSheet '<== change "Fruit Stock" as per your actual sheet name

    With Range("C1:D40")
        Set r = .Resize(.Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

        With r

            .Copy
            With .Offset(, .Columns.Count + 1)
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues ' copy value and formats
                .Columns(2).Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(C" & r.Column & ",RC" & r.Column & ",C[-" & .Columns.Count + 1 & "])"
                .Value = .Value
                .RemoveDuplicates 1, xlYes
            End With

        End With

End With
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The answer above has helped me but I have another problem. I need to replace duplicates removed with a nominal value for example "Duplicates". The reason I have 4 columns let's say, Fruit, Fruit Qty, Veg, Veg Qty. My vba code is consolidating Fruit and Fruit Qty to a designated 2 columns and Veg and Veg Qty to another designated 2 columns. The problem is that if the Fruit col has more duplicates than the Veg col the data gets shifted upwards to misalign. If I can replace the duplicates removed with "Duplicate I shouldn't have this problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: So if Fruit col had 4 duplicates and Veg col has 1 duplicate the misalignment is 3 cells.